# htacess rewrite causing trouble for a wordpress install

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Below is my htaccess that lets the user send a parameter by simply: http://www.site.com/PARAMETER. I have not got any trouble up until now everything works fine but I tried to install a wordpress-blog and put it under http://www.site.com/blog/ and now trying to access it, it does not work, the script enters the mode as when the parameter is false even if I try the exact URL: http://www.site.com/blog/index.php

```
IndexIgnore */*

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ lista.php?kod=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ lista.php?kod=$1

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.site.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?site.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .(gif|jpg)$ � [F]

<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

Worth to note is that I have another page on http://www.site.com/b/page.php which I can acess just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try explicitly telling mod_rewrite to ignore requests that match existing directories or files. Example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
```

When included at the top of the script (after `RewriteEngine On`), this should force the rewrite engine to stop rewriting a URL if it matches an existing directory or file.

Comment: Great, thank you. Additionally, from what you wrote, I wonder if I need to state RewriteEngine on several time as I have in my htaccess. Or in other words, is there anything else I could change in it?

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention exactly that :) One `RewriteEngine On` directive at the top of the file directive is sufficient. Also, you will probably need to move your hotlinking check above the directives I gave you. The order should be: no hotlinking, no existing files or directories, then your other rewriting rules.